# How can I find mdf/ldf locations in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I find mdf/ldf locations in SQL2008 using T-SQL?  Life is too short and error-prone to do it from the Properties screen.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT   DB_NAME(database_id) AS DatabaseName
        ,Name AS Logical_Name
        ,Physical_Name
        ,(size*8)/1024 SizeMB
FROM   sys.master_files
WHERE  DB_NAME(database_id) = 'Your_database_Name'
GO
```

or

```
Use Database_Name
GO

SELECT  name
       ,type_desc
       ,physical_name
       ,(size*8)/1024 SizeMB
FROM   sys.database_files
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select filename FROM sysfiles
```